# Does cycle_key destroy previous session?

Tags: django, session

I want to use this function [request.session.cycle_key()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.cycle_key) to rotate session key. In documentation it is said:

> cycle_key()
>
> Creates a new session key while retaining the current session 
>   data.django.contrib.auth.login() calls this method to mitigate against
>   session fixation.

So, it is not said whether the previous session is destroyed or not. However, this fact is crucial for ajax application, when there may be multiple parallel requests and so previous session may be destroyed (or not?) by one request, while at the same moment another request tries to access this previous (already destroyed?) session. This may cause serious problems in application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily see for yourself [in the source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8.2/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py#L287) that it does.

Comment: Is it possible to override this function, so that it will not destroy the previous session? How can I do this (for example in a view, where I use this `cycle_key` function)?

Comment: @Jacobian Probably just a matter of subclassing your current session backend and setting [`SESSION_ENGINE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_ENGINE). But if you’re calling `cycle_key` yourself, why not just call a private helper function instead? In either case, though, you need to watch out for breakage in newer Django versions: notice how `cycle_key` manipulates the private attribute `_session_cache`.